# iOS: access device microphone in background app

Tags: ios, avfoundation, microphone

Im wondering, is there a way for an app to access the Microphone of an iDevice while running in the background (The device may or may not be locked)?

I need to listen to the audio input and do some sound recognition.

Cheers from Mexico

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Apple's developer page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html), you can use the "audio" permission, which gives this access:

> The app plays audible content to the user or records audio while in the background. (This content includes streaming audio or video content using AirPlay.)

Comment: This was a longcoming. Any idea when this was added to the SDK?

Comment: Addendum: You can listen in the background ONLY IF the microphone is started when the phone is unlocked and the screen is on. Otherwise, starting it in the background does not seem to work today. Maybe this can change in a future version?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is possible.